Build a hierarchy of Windows features for Windows 10 and 11 using PowerShell
NOTE: This question is specifically about Windows 10 and 11, not Windows Server.
To get a list of Windows features on a given Windows 10 or 11 machine I know I have to use Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online in the DISM module.  Is there any way to determine the parent-child relationships of the features though?
For example, on my machine .NET Framework 4.8 Advanced Services is a top-level feature, which has WCF Services as a child, and that in turn has HTTP Activation as a child:

If I look at the results of Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online for each of these features, this is what I see:
$features = @('NetFx4-AdvSrvs', 'WCF-Services45', 'WCF-HTTP-Activation45')
$features | Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName { $_ }


The yellow arrows highlight the display names of the features, which match the names in the Windows Features dialog.
The red arrows highlight the ServerComponent\Parent custom properties of each feature, which seem like the only possibility for creating a feature hierarchy.  However, the values for the ServerComponent\Parent properties don't match the actual feature names of the parent features.
Is there some other way of determining the Windows 10 or 11 feature hierarchy in PowerShell?

Is UniqueName not what you're looking for?

@Luke, UniqueName doesn't quite work, at least not all the time.  For example, for WCF Services the ServerComponent\Parent is NET-Framework-45-Core but its parent (.NET Framework 4.8 Advanced Services) has the ServerComponent\UniqueName of NET-Framework-45-AdvSrvs.
